# How can i Query Google Analytics into S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-analytics

The idea is to query with a python script google analytics and insert into an S3 amazon bucket. I already have both but i would like to make this more automatic and let the script run every day from a server. I was looking to use another AWS to do it for me but i can't figure out which one.

In lambda i find i couldn't upload the .json with the credential to authenticate the Google APIs, do you know what service i should use?

Since the final idea is to create a Data Warehouse in redshift I'm trying to stay away from google services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AWS Lambda Scheduled events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html) for this. Also you can include the Google Access Credentials in environmental variables and access them inside Lambda, so that it is not available outside. You should be able to use [Google Analytics API SDK for JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js) to write it in NodeJS.

Note: Make sure your Lambda execution role has access to the S3 bucket.